# Emacs adds extra spaces to quoted strings when editing Python files

Tags: emacs

When working with Python files in emacs, I'm having an issue where, if I pause while typing a quoted string **and** have a space character at the end of that text, I will automatically advance to the next tab stop. I.e.,

```
"""Foobar """
```

Turns into

```
"""Foobar  """
```

I'm both old and new to using emacs (I first tried using it over 20 years ago, but am now seriously trying to make the switch), and I haven't been able to figure out what is doing this. I've tried the following:

- Disabling all extra modules.
- Disabling sections of my init.el file.
- Disabling everything in my init.el file.
- Starting emacs with "emacs -Q" (this is the only thing that works).

This doesn't happen with ANY other mode I use. If I load any add'l modules it seems to happen.

Has anybody seen this before?

Help?

Comment: My first suggestion would be, restart your editor. Hopefully, that would fix it!

Comment: Just as a side note: Your write-up of the problem you are facing is good, but as a whole the question would definitely benefit from a better title.

Comment: @S.M.AlMamun - I've restarted the editor multiple times and the issue persists.

Comment: Emacs version? I don't understand how your example has a closed string, but yet you're paused on the line? doing what? about to go to the next line? write a comment? I have witnessed weirdness in python-mode before, but I can't recreate what you're talking about or even fully understand the process you're describing that's triggering it.

Comment: Sorry - Emacs version is 24.3. That's an example of when it's most annoying - when I'm writing a docstring. But I could just as easily have used the example: 'spam ' turns into 'spam    '. And yes, I'm just paused on the line after the space, thinking about what I'm doing. Thanks.

Comment: @Jack - It also only happens when I'm working on a strong with quotes, whether I just have the opening quote, or I'm editing a string already with the quotes around it.

Comment: Most important stuff which idles and fiddles around with the appearance of the buffer is `font-lock`. Please disable `font-lock-mode` and try again. Just type `M-x font-lock-mode`. The minibuffer should show `Font-Lock mode disabled`. With disabled `font-lock-mode` test whether the problem is gone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some hook seems to insert `TAB`, maybe from a `tab-to-tab-stop` function. BTW which python-mode is in use - from python.el or python-mode.el? If the latter, which version?

To find the hook, <kbd>M-x</kbd> describe-key <kbd>RET SPACE</kbd>. It will bring up a HELP-buffer, where the hooks called by default are mentioned at the bottom. Check the functions there.

Comment: I'm using python-mode 6.1.3. I'll try to track it down as you suggested and report back.

Thanks.

Comment: @DarthBob Thanks. Think detected the spot already. Maybe follow here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode/+bug/1330045

Comment: @DarthBob Checked in a fix. Please try with current trunk.

Comment: I've been offline since Friday and will not be able to try the fix until this evening (this is an issue I'm specifically having at home; my work emacs config is slightly different; I haven't had the opportunity to sync them up yet...) I'll try it tonight and get back to you. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Hmm. I've updated to the most recent trunk, and I'm still having that issue. I'll do the describe key to see whether I can identify what's up.

Comment: OK. I've gone back in and completely stripped out every other module but python-mode (again). This time when I strip out every other module, I'm NOT having the issue. When I add the modules back in and do `M-x` `describe-key` `RET` `Space`, it shows `self-insert-command-adviced`. I did a search for that hook in every `.el` file in my tree, but I can't locate it. Only 3 modules in my `.emacs.d` reference `self-insert-command`. These are: `auto-complete`, `python-mode`, & `yasnippet`. I think it's probably NOT python-mode causing it, but can't narrow it down further. Thoughts?

Comment: @DarthBob Detected another suspicious spot, fixed with r1546. Beside TAB might be inserted if now word to complete is before cursor.

Comment: Still happening to me. As I said in one of my previous posts, I **think** this may be an issue from one of my other modules, just wish I could track it down. However, just to validate I'm downloading the correct branch (I'm more accustomed to using `git` than `bazaar`), the proper command to do the download is `bzr branch lp:python-mode`, correct? Thanks.

Comment: Nevermind...I just popped open `bzr explorer`, and I downloaded and am currently running r1553.